# tempdb move issue

Tags: tempdb

In preparation for moving many of my databases in a data warehouse to READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation level (CDC and Reads contend for locks) I added a drive and moved my tempdb there (mdf and ldf) using the ALTER DATABASE command, or at least I thought I did. My script didn't include my 7 ndf files so I moved them with the same command. Now, when I look at the tempdb properties or with sp_help, none of the ndf files are listed and they aren't in the Primary filegroup (I only have the one file group). Can I re-associate the ndf files with the filegroup and if so how?

BTW: MS SQL2016 SP1, OS WinServ 2012 R2 (x64)

Comment: Eh, it's tempdb, I'd just recreate them.

Comment: Did you restart the service?

Answer (score 0):

Cliff.

The easiest way is to do the following:

1. Add as many files as you need to `TempDB` (but take a look at [MS
   recommendations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2154845/recommendations-to-reduce-allocation-contention-in-sql-server-tempdb-d) first; also reading [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/cheat-sheet-how-to-configure-tempdb-for-microsoft-sql-server/) Brent Ozar post
   might be helpful) with this T-SQL:

   > ```
   > ALTER DATABASE tempdb ADD FILE(NAME = N'<LogicalName>', FILENAME = N'<path&filename>', SIZE = <size>, FILEGROWTH = <growth>); GO
   > ```
2. Restart SQL Server service

These two simple actions should help you solve your issue!